# Maximal split into two groups

Tags: statistics, graph-theory, optimization

Suppose we have $2N$ players and let the animosity between players $i$ and $j$ be denoted by $x_{i,j}$. $x_{i,j}$ is symmetric ($x_{i,j} = x_{j,i}$) and for each player we know the animosity between that player and $p<2N$ other players, other values are unknown.

Now we want to create 2 groups of $N$ players such that the animosity between the groups is maximal. Do you have any suggestion on how to create these groups? Some results from graph theory that might be useful here? Also, how 'good' is the group allocation for a given $p$? Can we do any statistics?

Example with $N=3$ and $p=2$:

$x_{1,6} = 2$, $x_{1,2} = 7$, $x_{2,3}=8$, $x_{3,4}=9$, $x_{4,5} = 3$, $x_{5,6}=6$

The best split seems to be $\{1,3,6\}$ and $\{2,4,5\}$

Comment: This sounds liek the weighted Max-Cut problem (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut).  DOes that sound right ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a maximum weight balanced bipartite subgraph, which is similar to a maximum cut, but you additionally require both sets of players to have the same cardinality. Finding a maximum weight bipartite subgraph is equivalent to finding a maximum cut.

Maximum cut is NP-complete, but I couldn't find any hardness results for the balanced version.

**Addendum**: In case that $p = 2$ and the graph is connected, it is always possible to put two players $i$, $j$ with $x_{i,j} > 0$ in different groups, because the graph is a circle of even length. Hence the animosity between the groups is the sum over all $x_{i,j}$'s in this case. More generally, this holds if $p = 2$ and the graph is the union of circles of even length.

Your example can therefore be improved by grouping $\{1,3,5\}$ and $\{2,4,6\}$, which yields a total animosity of 35, whereas your split only yields 30.

**Addendum 2**: As a heuristic, one could use [Edmonds's Blossom Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) to find a perfect maximum weight matching, then remove the matching arcs and re-run the algorithm on the remaining graph. If I'm not mistaken, the matching arcs of both runs then form a set of circles of even length, which can be treated as described above.